# The following error message appears when i run dpkg on linux ? What is the issus?

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I used this command for removing the linux-image

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

But it shows the following error message

```
(Reading database ... 267739 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic (4.4.0-116.140) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-116-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-116-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: ruto#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic.postrm line 330.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

What is the issue? I am not able to install new packages because of files like this. Please help.

These are the contents of my /etc/default/grub file

```
ruto# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: `/etc/default/grub: ruto#: not found` - have you examined the contents of the file mentioned?

Comment: I have added the contents of the grub file . Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of the "ruto" in this line in your grub file

`ruto# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update`

You must have been editing it and made a mistake. This line should start with the # sign.

Comment: Thank you , i am able to install new packages again

Comment: Glad it helped! Since you're new to the site, if you consider this answer correct, please mark it by clicking the grey checkmark.

Comment: Okay thank you so much  and an a good observation .